# Simple Traffic Flow Problem - Interaction Probability

Tags: probability, modeling, model

Suppose you have a section of road with two-way traffic, and some basic information about traffic volumes, for example:

Let $l_a$ be the number of light vehicles per hour that travel across this road in one direction, and let $h_a$ be the number of heavy vehicles per hour that travel across the road in the same direction. Similarly, Let $l_b$ and $h_b$ be the number of light and heavy vehicles that travel across the road per hour in the opposite direction. We should assume that these are *random* - so I suppose, for any given vehicle, the time that they would begin to cross this section of road would have a uniform distribution.

Assume that any vehicle takes $x$ seconds to travel across this section of road.

How could one calculate the probability that a *light* vehicle will interact with an opposing *heavy* vehicle on this section of road, say, in any given hour?

I'm not used to this aspect of *time* in probability calculations, since I've only done second year university statistics. Would we have to discretize the problem somehow?

Comment: If you assume a continuous distribution, I think you may run into the problem that $P(T=t)=0$ almost everywhere by definition. You should, however, be able to calculate thing like the joint time spent by both vehicles between the intersection.
Discretise looks like the way to go :)

Comment: Essentially, assume that the vehicles, independently, enter the intersection with a uniform jump process (arrive with uniform between $t=t_1$ and $t=t_2$), then since the distance and speed is fixed, they only interact (I assume you mean pass each other whilst both in the intersection) if the vehicles are 1. coming in opposite directions and 2. one does not enter after the other has passed. You may want to run a simulation! This could be even more interesting if the vehicles have a random speed!